# GWT SuperDev mode enabled, source maps enabled, compiled, yet no source maps appear

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

As the title says, I'm attempting to run SuperDev mode using the latest version of GWT (2.6.1) in Chrome.

My application is being served by a Tomcat server. I have the SuperDev mode server running (via IntelliJ), which compiles and links the sources successfully, and source maps are enabled in Chrome. I go to the application (`http://localhost:8081/example/#example`). When it loads, I compile using the DevMode On bookmark. When it's done compiling, I don't see any Java sources in the Chrome developer tools.

I also have the following properties set in my applications `.gwt.xml`

`<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />`

I'm not sure what else I'm missing? From the various resources I've found online, it appears I have all of my bases covered, so I'm not sure why the source maps won't show up.

Comment: When you navigate to gwtproject.org do you see sourcemaps? If not, you might be using beta/canary Chrome, which has been frequently known to break this feature. Can you also verify that you haven't unchecked the sourcemaps checkbox in the dev tools? Finally, do you see the log message `[WARN] sent source map for module:` in your super dev mode process console?

Comment: I can see the sourcemaps on gwtproject.org (and I'm using the latest stable version of Chrome). I don't see that log message in the dev mode process console. I do see `[WARN] ignored get request: /sourcemaps/log/WebApp` though. And yes, I can confirm that the sourcemaps checkbox is checked in Chrome.

Comment: Can you look at the Network tab in DevTools: what's in the `X-SourceMap` response header for the `.nocache.js`? is there a request for a `gwtSourceMap.json`? (also, it's strange that it looks for `/sourceMaps/log/WebApp`, that shouldn't happen; in the `gwtSourceMap.json` response, does it talk about that URL? anything related to `WebApp`?)

Comment: I don't see a request for `gwtSourceMap.json`. This is what my response header looks like for the `.nocache.js` request. `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
ETag: W/"7401-1402513602636"
Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 19:10:19 GMT`

Answer (score 3):

The problem likely is that your `.gwt.xml` allows several permutations, but SuperDevMode cannot provide source map for several versions of code. Check the logs of SuperDevMode process - it should have corresponding message there.

So, just try to make your module in `.gwt.xml` produce only one permutation. If you use standard GWT libs only, it would be enough to place there

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

For GXT-driven project, use this one instead:

```
<set-property name="gxt.user.agent" value="chrome" />
```

For MGWT-driven project try to use these lines:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
<set-property name="mgwt.os" value="desktop" />
```

As a positive side-effect of having only one permutation will be the shortest re-compiling time for your project when you develop it ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You saved my day! Had exactly the same problem and kept checking dev tool settings...