# GWT Super dev mode stopped working under Chrome, no request for source maps

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, source-maps, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm using GWT 2.7.0 with GXT 3.1.1 and IntelliJ 15.0.5 and Chrome 50. I debug my application using the Super Dev Mode (with a separate code server and bookmarklets) and up to now it's worked quite well.

However, for no apparent reason, today the Super Dev Mode has stopped working under Chrome (I can get it to work under IE 11). Everything works as before, but my *.java files are no longer visible in the Chrome Dev Tools.

I've been doing clean-and-rebuild (including cleaning gwt-unitCache), checking SO posts, reconfiguring SDM in IntelliJ, but so far nothing's helped.

Here's what I've managed to find out (inspired but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164990/gwt-superdev-mode-enabled-source-maps-enabled-compiled-yet-no-source-maps-app)):

1. Source maps are enabled
2. I can see source maps on gwtproject.org
3. In Chrome's Network tab I can see 2 requests for *.nocache.js (one to my server, the other to the code server). Neither of these requests has the `X-SourceMap` response header
4. There is NO request for `gwtSourceMap.json`
5. There is nothing interesting in the Super Dev Mode logs, this is the only reference to anything source-map-related:

   ```
       Linking per-type JS with 5560 new types.
          prelink JS size = 11286518
          prelink sourcemap = 11286518 bytes and 260145 lines
          postlink JS size = 10968640
          postlink sourcemap = 10968640 bytes and 253152 lines
       Source Maps Enabled
    Compile of permutations succeeded
    Compilation succeeded -- 34,546s
   ```

I have a separate module file for Super Dev Mode with just 1 permutation:

```
<set-property name="gxt.user.agent" value="chrome"/>
<set-property-fallback name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
```

I'm starting to run out of ideas (other than going through gwt sources), any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem today with similar symptoms.
Eventually found that in chrome dev tool, i'd blacklisted an important gwt js file (project-0.js). I just didn't want to see it in tracebacks when i was debugging some native js stuff, but with that blacklisted, the sourcemaps weren't getting pulled in! Once I un-blacklisted it, I could once again load and debug gwt java in cdt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've just disabled blackboxing for project-0.js and I can see the source maps again :)

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome 69 and gwt.2.7.0 on Mac OS, but under Settings / Blackbox there is nothing set. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem and I made sure that I didn't blacklisted anything. Do you have anything mind?